# JavaScript RegExp - find all prefixes up to a certain character

Tags: javascript, regex, prefix

I have a string which is composed of terms separated by slashes (`'/'`), for example:

```
ab/c/def
```

I want to find all the prefixes of this string up to an occurrence of a slash or end of string, i.e. for the above example I expect to get:

```
ab
ab/c
ab/c/def
```

I've tried a regex like this: `/^(.*)[\/$]/`, but it returns a single match - `ab/c/` with the parenthesized result `ab/c`, accordingly.

### EDIT :

I know this can be done quite easily using `split`, I am looking specifically for a solution using `RegExp`.

Comment: only with regex? i think it's impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## NO, you can't do that with a pure regex.

**Why?** Because you need substrings starting at one and the same location in the string, while regex matches non-overlapping chunks of text and then advances its index to search for another match.

**OK, what about capturing groups?** They are only helpful if you know how many `/`-separated chunks you have in the input string. You could then use

```js
var  s = 'ab/c/def'; // There are exact 3 parts
console.log(/^(([^\/]+)\/[^\/]+)\/[^\/]+$/.exec(s));
// => [ "ab/c/def", "ab/c", "ab" ]
```

*However*, it is unlikely you know that many details about your input string.

You may use the following code rather than a regex:

```js
var  s = 'ab/c/def';
var chunks = s.split('/');
var res = [];
for(var i=0;i<chunks.length;i++) {
  res.length > 0 ? res.push(chunks.slice(0,i).join('/')+'/'+chunks[i]) : res.push(chunks[i]);
}
console.log(res);
```

First, you can split the string with `/`. Then, iterate through the elements and build the `res` array.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think a regular expression is what you are after. A simple split and loop over the array can give you the result.

```
var str = "ab/c/def";
var result = str.split("/").reduce(function(a,s,i){
    var last = a[i-1] ? a[i-1] + "/" : "";
    a.push(last + s);
    return a;
}, []);
console.log(result);
```

or another way

```
var str = "ab/c/def",
    result = [], 
    parts=str.split("/");
while(parts.length){
    console.log(parts);
    result.unshift(parts.join("/"));
    parts.pop();
}
console.log(result);
```

Plenty of other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with a RegEx in javascript but you can split parts and join them respectively together:

```js
var array = "ab/c/def".split('/'), newArray = [], key = 0;
while (value = array[key++]) {
    newArray.push(key == 1 ? value : newArray[newArray.length - 1] + "/" + value)
}
console.log(newArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

May be like this

```js
var str = "ab/c/def",
 result = str.match(/.+?(?=\/|$)/g)
             .map((e,i,a) => a[i-1] ? a[i] = a[i-1] + e : e);
 console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you just split the string on the separator character?

```js
var result = 'ab/c/def'.split(/\//g);
```

Comment: That is not what the OP is looking for

Comment: Perhaps the OP could explain why split isn't usable in this scenario?  As @Laurianti mentioned, I don't think it is possible to write a regex match with an indeterminate number of groups.